# Connecting to SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-ce

I created a simple Windows CE application with Visual Studio 2008 using Compact Framework 3.5. I am using SQL server 2008 on the same PC. How can I connect to the database from my application?  Currently I am using the Visual Studio Device Emulator.

I tried this:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=192.168.10.127,1433;Initial Catalog=school;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from students",SqlConn);
SqlDataAdapter dr=new SqlDataAdapter();
dr.SelectCommand=cmd;
dr.Fill(dt);
dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

But exceptions occurred. Please help.

Comment: What "exceptions"?  I don't see you passing in a username and password, so that's likely a problem.

Comment: This is Windows authentication (Integrated Security=SSPI), so user name and password are not required. Exception details would be really helpful.

Comment: From Windows CE there is no Windows authentication (well not without some nasty P/Invokes that I'm 99.9% certain the OP isn't doing), so you can't have "integrated" security.  SSPI is effectively a NOP under CE.  There need to be credentials passed here.

Comment: here is a stack     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(String host, SqlInternalConnection connHandler, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor(SqlConnection connection, Hashtable connectionOptions)

Comment: SQL server authentication mode is windows mode, i access without passowrd